# Implementation Issue Migrate Cognito UserPool with Lambda Trigger for iOS

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

Migrated AWS Cognito Old UserPool to New UserPool. And also wrote the lambda trigger for the same. Lambda trigger seems to working in AWS Lambda Test but not getting triggered when I sign in with Application.

Just to describe the question in detail.I have iOS App in which I have migrated the user pool and after doing some reading got to know about the change of authorization flow that needs to be implemented in the code. Use of ADMIN_USER_PASSWORD_AUTH challenge in code for having non_SRP username and password. Unable to figure how to implement it in authorize method of the code.
In short To invoke the User Migration Trigger how to auth using USER_PASSWORD_AUTH?

```
func getDetails(_ authenticationInput: AWSCognitoIdentityPasswordAuthenticationInput,
                passwordAuthenticationCompletionSource: AWSTaskCompletionSource<AWSCognitoIdentityPasswordAuthenticationDetails>) {
    if currentUsername == nil || currentPassword == nil {
        return
    }

    let authDetail = AWSCognitoIdentityPasswordAuthenticationDetails.init(username: currentUsername!,
                                                                          password: currentPassword!)
    
    passwordAuthenticationCompletionSource.set(result: authDetail)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After struggling for 2 days, I was able to figure out the solution. It seems that when we migrate the Cognito user pool we need to change the auth flow. The default the auth flow is the SRP flow but that doesn't trigger the migration. Changes needs to be made but in AWSCognitoIdentityUserPoolConfiguration func need to enable migrationEnabled to true.

```
 let userPoolConfig = AWSCognitoIdentityUserPoolConfiguration(clientId: AWSUserPoolClientId, clientSecret: AWSUserPoolClientSecret, poolId: AWSUserPoolId, shouldProvideCognitoValidationData: true, pinpointAppId: nil , migrationEnabled: true )
```

Note: please refer https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-dg.pdf page 72 for more details. And other small thing to keep in mind AWS has small mistake in

[image]

AWS documentation kindly set shouldProvideCognitoValidationData: true & migrationEnabled: true instead of YES which is the case in Objective-C